# Почему не срабатывает код

Tags: html, jquery

Так работает

```
<button type="submit" class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 header_nav_button_search ml-md-0" onclick="search_start()"><img src="img/search.png" alt="search"></button>

function search_start(){...}
```

А так нет

```
<button type="submit" class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 header_nav_button_search ml-md-0"><img src="img/search.png" alt="search"></button>

$('.header_nav_button_search').click(function(){...})
```

Comment: А у вас этот поиск не динамически подгружается? Попробуйте так - `$(document).on('click', '.header_nav_button_search', function(){ ... });`

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что код не срабатывает?

Answer (score 0):

Как можете наблюдать, код работает.

```js
$('.header_nav_button_search').click(function() {
  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 header_nav_button_search ml-md-0"><img src="img/search.png" alt="search"></button>
```

Он может не работать из-за того, что находится в форме и при нажатии кнопки `button type="submit"` вы отправляете форму обрабатываться.
Для этого нужно использовать "отключить" обработку формы, допустим таким образом

```js
$('.header_nav_button_search').click(function() {
  alert('click');
  return false; // Отменяем отправку формы.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/">
<button type="submit" class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 header_nav_button_search ml-md-0"><img src="img/search.png" alt="search"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: И я бы использовал `.on('click', function(){})`

Comment: Убрал вообще `type='submit'` все равно не работает.

Comment: Заменил на `.on('click', function(){})` все равно не работает

Comment: Что пишет консоль (F12 -> Console)?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, `.on('click', function(){})` - это то же самое что и `.click(function(){})`

Comment: У меня JS файл подключался до создания кнопки. А кнопка создавалась динамически. Когда я перенес подключения JS файла в самый конец. Все заработало